# Django duplicate queries

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize my django app using select and prefetch related but for some reason it doesn't work
this is my models :

```py
    class Question(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        content = models.TextField()
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='avatar.png')
```

and this is my `serializers` :

```py
    class EagerLoadingMixin:
        @classmethod
        def setup_eager_loading(cls, queryset):
            if hasattr(cls, "_SELECT_RELATED_FIELDS"):
                queryset = queryset.select_related(*cls._SELECT_RELATED_FIELDS)
            if hasattr(cls, "_PREFETCH_RELATED_FIELDS"):
                queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(*cls._PREFETCH_RELATED_FIELDS)
            return queryset

    class QuestionSerializer(EagerLoadingMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
        profile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

        class Meta:
            model = Question
            fields = (
                'id',
                'title',
                'author',
                'profile',
                'content',
            )

        _SELECT_RELATED_FIELDS = ['author']
        _PREFETCH_RELATED_FIELDS = ['author__profile']

   
        @staticmethod
        def get_profile(obj):
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=obj.author)
            return ProfileSerializer(profile).data
```

but that's what I get in django debug toolbar:

```sql
SELECT ••• FROM "accounts_profile" WHERE "accounts_profile"."user_id" = 14 LIMIT 21`
```

and 10 similar queries.

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: anyways  putting doublequotes in table names and column names seems like no is not syntax of any dbms , if you are using mysql it should be singlequote

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: Can you add how you are using it in the view?